# Accessing the SerialPort class using .Net Core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, serial-port, serial-communication, .net-core-3.0

I'm starting a new .NET Core 3.0 project in which I need to access the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort class. The documentation I'm reading on the class shows that it is applicable to .NET Core 3 ( see the bottom of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=netcore-3.0 ). However when I add a using statement to my class it isn't able to resolve System.IO.Ports. Is there some additional step that needs to be done to reference the SerialPort class for a .NET Core 3.0 program running on the Windows desktop?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found the answer a few moments after I posted this question. To use the SerialPort class there is an additional package that needs to be installed. I was able click QuickActions icon to install the package.

[image]

Comment: Awesome , thanks for your good explantation @Joel

Answer (score 14):

I am using **.NET Core 3.1** building **Blazor** app.
**Visual Studio 2019** did not gave me context menu item "Install package 'System.IO.Ports'". I resolve this by going to DOS prompt.

```
cd <project_path>
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration --version 5.0.0
dotnet add package System.IO.Ports --version 5.0.0
```

That seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue and this worked for me. Just I downloaded and installed the package and all ok.
Thanks.

You need to do the following:
Tools > Command Line > Developer Command Prompt
and execute the following commands: dotnet add package System.IO.Ports

You can also add it through NuGet packages.

Comment: You should add to your answer what package was it.

Comment: Go to Tools>Command Line>Developer Command Prompt
and  following commands:
dotnet add package System.IO.Ports