# Read from Serial Port on Blazor

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am new in Blazor and I am trying to create an app reading from a serial port.
At first, I created a  console application using .Core 3.1
Everything worked fined so I moved the code to Blazor and although when I put debug point I can see that the code works I cannot make the UI to show the value

```
@using System;
@using System.Diagnostics;
@using System.IO.Ports;
@using System.Threading;


<head>
    <title>Main Scale Monitor</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<div class="scale-monitor">
    <div class="digital-monitor net-weight grid-line">
        <div class="digital-monitor-left net-left">NET</div>
        <div class="digital-monitor-center net-center" bind="@ScaleValue"></div>
        <div class="digital-monitor-right net-right">Kg</div>
    </div>
</div>


@code {

    public string ScaleValue { get; set; } = "0.001";

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            System.IO.Ports.SerialPort mySerialPort = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM3");

            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            mySerialPort.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;

            mySerialPort.NewLine = (@"&N");

            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

            if (!mySerialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                mySerialPort.Open();

            }
        }
    }


    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.Ports.SerialPort sp = (System.IO.Ports.SerialPort)sender;

        try
        {
            string indata = sp.ReadLine();
            ScaleValue = indata.ToString(); //WHEN I PUT DEBUG HERE I CAN SEE THE CORRECT VALUE

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.Message;
        }

    }
}


<style>

    *, ::after, ::before {
        box-sizing: unset;
    }

    .grid-line {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .scale-monitor {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 35% 35% 30%;
        grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 90%;
        margin: 5px;
        width: 1020px;
    }


    /*#region generic*/

    .digital-monitor {
        background: #000000;
        color: greenyellow;
        text-align: right;
        font-family: digitalregular;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
        width: 95%;
        height: 95%;
        margin: 5px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        align-items: center;
    }

    /*#region generic scalemonitor*/
    .digital-monitor-left {
        writing-mode: vertical-rl;
        opacity: 0.5;
        grid-row: 1 / span 5;
        grid-column: 1;
        text-align: center;
        grid-column: 1;
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }

    .digital-monitor-center {
        grid-row: 2 / span 3;
        grid-column: 2/ span 7;
        text-align: right;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }

    .digital-monitor-right {
        grid-row: 2 / span 3;
        grid-column: 9/ span 2;
        text-align: right;
        opacity: 0.75;
        margin-bottom: 0.4em;
        margin-right: 3px;
        align-self: self-end;
    }
    /*#endregion*/

    /*#endregion*/


    /*#region NET*/
    .net-weight {
        grid-column: 2;
        grid-row: 1 / span 2;
        height: 98%;
    }

    .net-left {
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    .net-center {
        font-size: 100px;
    }

    .net-right {
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    /*#endregion NET*/
</style>
```

Any idea of how I could do the correct binding?

Comment: Are you referring to Blazor client or server?

Comment: @Artak Blazor server

Comment: Does bind work on div? I never tried it. Try <div>@ScaleValue</doc>

Comment: You do realize that this is the Serial port _on the Server_, right?  You can't read the port from inside a Browser.

Comment: The application at the end will become a desktop app (using electron) @HenkHolterman

Comment: ok - just checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an answer,
I am not 100% this is the best solution

Create a service

```
public class ReadSerialPortService
{
    public string SerialPortValue { get; set; }

    public ReadSerialPortService()
    {
        System.IO.Ports.SerialPort mySerialPort = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM3");

        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;

        mySerialPort.NewLine = (@"&N");

        if (!mySerialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            mySerialPort.Open();
        }
    }

    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.Ports.SerialPort sp = (System.IO.Ports.SerialPort)sender;
        double scaleDec = 0.00;
        try
        {
            string indata = sp.ReadLine();
            SerialPortValue = indata.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.Message;
        }

    }

    public Task<string> GetSerialValue()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(SerialPortValue);
    }
}
```

And then in the component

```
@inject ReadSerialPortService _readSerialPortService
<head>
   <title>Main Scale Monitor</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link href="/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div class="scale-monitor">
   <div class="digital-monitor net-weight grid-line" @onclick="GetValue">
      <div class="digital-monitor-left net-left">NET</div>
      <div class="digital-monitor-center net-center">@ScaleValue</div>
      <div class="digital-monitor-right net-right">Kg</div>
   </div>
</div>


@code {
private int Count { get; set; } = 100;
Timer _updateTimer;
public string ScaleValue { get; set; } = "0.000";    

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    ScaleValue = await _readSerialPortService.GetSerialValue();
    _updateTimer = new Timer(state => { InvokeAsync(GetValue); }, null, 0, 100);
}


public async Task GetValue()
{
    ScaleValue = await _readSerialPortService.GetSerialValue();
    await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
}

public void Dispose()
{
    _updateTimer.Dispose();
}
```

}

Comment: You can remove all the async (Task, await) stuff from GetValue() and GetSerialValue(), they are just polling and that is fast and synchronous. Be aware that a string is 'thread-safe' , you can't share more complex data (double, decimal) this way.

Comment: Hello @Nianios, I Implemented your solution and it's working fine for local server, after pushing code on aws server it's giving me console error "Access to the port 'COM3' is denied"
Can you help for above issue?

Answer (score 2):

From the Blazor Lifecycle [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#after-component-render):
"Asynchronous work immediately after rendering must occur during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle event.

Even if you return a Task from OnAfterRenderAsync, the framework doesn't schedule a further render cycle for your component once that task completes. This is to avoid an infinite render loop. It's different from the other lifecycle methods, which schedule a further render cycle once the returned task completes."

Try to call the `StateHasChanged()` manually after the `ScaleValue` is set.

Comment: When I call the StateHasChanged I get : The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher. Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state. DO you have any good examples for this?

Comment: Will try this out now, and get back to you.

Comment: Can you try this:

    await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());

Comment: Of course this would require to change the event handle to `async`

Comment: @Artak and @ Nianos: I think it is better (safer) to keep the event  as-is and just fire that InvokeAsync() without an await.

Comment: There is no much difference, actually, because your event handler `DataReceivedHandler` is already `void`. That said, However, if you not await on the `InvokeAsync` call, I think you will receive a compiler warning about it.
That said, I would go with the `await InvokeAsync` option.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sits where you try and bind the value to the div.

The `div` element is not a component and will not support the bind attribute.

Try this: `<div class="digital-monitor-center net-center">@ScaleValue</div>`

Since your code is not relying on the render of the page, set it to use another lifecycle method.

Try putting it in `protected override void OnInitialized() { }`

**Edit:**

Read up on Blazor's lifecycles here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1

**Edit: Code Example**

```
@using System;
@using System.Diagnostics;
@using System.IO.Ports;
@using System.Threading;

@page "/Test";


<head>
    <title>Main Scale Monitor</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<div class="scale-monitor">
    <div class="digital-monitor net-weight grid-line">
        <div class="digital-monitor-left net-left">NET</div>
        <div class="digital-monitor-center net-center">@ScaleValue</div>
        <div class="digital-monitor-right net-right">Kg</div>
    </div>
</div>


@code {

    public string ScaleValue { get; set; } = "0.001";

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {

        System.IO.Ports.SerialPort mySerialPort = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM3");

        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;

        mySerialPort.NewLine = (@"&N");

        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        ScaleValue = "test";

        //I skipped this part with a return, since I don't have COM3 locally

        if (!mySerialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            mySerialPort.Open();

        }
    }


    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.Ports.SerialPort sp = (System.IO.Ports.SerialPort)sender;

        try
        {
            string indata = sp.ReadLine();
            ScaleValue = indata.ToString(); //WHEN I PUT DEBUG HERE I CAN SEE THE CORRECT VALUE

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.Message;
        }

    }
}


<style>

    *, ::after, ::before {
        box-sizing: unset;
    }

    .grid-line {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .scale-monitor {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 35% 35% 30%;
        grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 90%;
        margin: 5px;
        width: 1020px;
    }


    /*#region generic*/

    .digital-monitor {
        background: #000000;
        color: greenyellow;
        text-align: right;
        font-family: digitalregular;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
        width: 95%;
        height: 95%;
        margin: 5px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        align-items: center;
    }

    /*#region generic scalemonitor*/
    .digital-monitor-left {
        writing-mode: vertical-rl;
        opacity: 0.5;
        grid-row: 1 / span 5;
        grid-column: 1;
        text-align: center;
        grid-column: 1;
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }

    .digital-monitor-center {
        grid-row: 2 / span 3;
        grid-column: 2/ span 7;
        text-align: right;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }

    .digital-monitor-right {
        grid-row: 2 / span 3;
        grid-column: 9/ span 2;
        text-align: right;
        opacity: 0.75;
        margin-bottom: 0.4em;
        margin-right: 3px;
        align-self: self-end;
    }
    /*#endregion*/

    /*#endregion*/


    /*#region NET*/
    .net-weight {
        grid-column: 2;
        grid-row: 1 / span 2;
        height: 98%;
    }

    .net-left {
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    .net-center {
        font-size: 100px;
    }

    .net-right {
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    /*#endregion NET*/
</style>
```

Comment: The <div>@ScakeValue</div> doesn't work neither works the OnInitialized.

Comment: I included the code you supplied with my recommended changes, and it works fine. Check for my latest edit.

Comment: @Nianios, What do you mean by it doesn't work? What doesn't work?

Comment: First, the OnInitalized is crashed during the second pass, because the serial port is already under reading mode (the check for IsOpen doesn't work)
Even if I jump this point, the UI does not updated

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this posting. It really helps me.

I am using **.NET Core 3.1** building **Blazor** app.

"system.io.ports.serialport" is not incuded in the standard .NET Core. It is an extension package. To install, please check this posting https://stackoverflow.com/a/64786623/6192940.